# How to create time series collection in mongoDB using Nestjs and mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, time-series, nestjs

I am trying to create a time series schema using mongoose in Nestjs. Here's my schema -

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type NewUserModel = NewUser & Document;

@Schema({
  timeseries: {
    timeField: 'timeStamp',
    metaField: 'Name',
    granularity: 'seconds',
  },
})
export class NewUser {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  readonly Name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  readonly Skills: string;

  @Prop({ type: Date })
  readonly timeStamp: Date;
}

export const NewUserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(NewUser);
```

And here's the json request that I am sending through postman -

```
{
    "Name": "Nikolia Mangan",
    "Skills": "Management",
    "timeStamp": "2022-06-22T06:22:57.606+00:00"
}
```

This creates a collection but not a time series collection. I can confirm that by running this command in the shell -

```
db.runCommand( { listCollections: 1.0 } )
```

Which in turn returns the output -

```
"type" : "collection",
```

Comment: Using the `timeseries` option on the Schema decorator works for me with nestjs 9.2.1 and mongoose 6.7.2

Comment: @ChristofAenderl I switched to another database (client requirement) so I left the question as it is and switched to TypeORM. I have left this question open because just in case if someone comes along and has a solution for this exact problem then they would be able to help a of lot other people in future who are working on old versions of these libraries .

Comment: Facing the same issue in 2023 Oct

Comment: Facing the same issue in 2023 Dec, mongoose 7.0.3, nestjs 10.1.16